# What required sizes for designing full screen image to support multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout

i create magazine app which magazine pages consist of images and will be displayed in full screen. i want to know what the required sizes in pixels to design images to support all screens and images displayed good and not stretched.
Consider  i read the following topics:

1-http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

2-http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

3-http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

mostly it depends on different types of screen but yet try to use weight and weightsum attributes it will solve your problem